# Jersey - Rest API (Json Format)

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I am trying to create an Jersey application and I would like to pass the output to web browser in Json format. Below are the codes. I can only pass the data in xml format and when I change to "application/json" format, "HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error" came out. Any advice? thanks.

```
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/emp")
public class EmployeeService {

    @GET
    @Path("/get/{empID}")   
    @Produces({"application/json"})
    public Employee getEmployee(@PathParam("empID") String empID){
        Employee employee = new com.rest.employee.model.Employee();
        employee.setEmpID(empID);
        employee.setName("George");
        employee.setEmail("george@gmail.com");
        return employee;
        }
}
```

and another java file

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name="employee")

public class Employee {
    public String empID;
    public String name;
    public String email;

    @XmlElement(required=true)
    public String getEmpID() {
        return empID;
    }
    public void setEmpID(String empID) {
        this.empID = empID;
    }

    @XmlElement(required=true)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlElement(required=true)
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Comment: hey can you show what was your json request?
and if possible the console output it has a lot of information in these cases

Comment: Normally I will just use @Produces({"application/xml"}) to get xml output. But now I want to get Json file. So I change it to @Produces({"application/json"})... which lead to the error.

The request should come out the empID, Name and the email.

Comment: try adding @Consumes({"application/json"})

Answer (score 0):

The code looks 'nearly' fine and works for me as expected, but your `Employee` should implement Serializable. I can't see any other problem in there for now, so the problem is somewhere else i guess.

You said, that its not working anymore, since you changed from XML to JSON. So i reckon, that you miss a dependency for JSON. Check this ...

But in fact, the missing dependency should not result in an 500. Can it be true, that you have added a `ExceptionMapper` and that you throw your 500 by yourself?

Comment: I only have this 2 files in the whole project. So I dont think the error is throw by myself. Is it possible because of I am using the latest jersey jar file (2.12)? I am thinking there might be changing of format from the latest jersey. Could you please upload the code that you do? thanks.

Comment: Really strange, 'cause if you don't have a matching marshaller, you should get a E406 (Not Acceptable) instead of an E500 (Internal Server Error). If you really just have 2 files (Employee.java, EmployeeService.java) you never ever saw the Employee serialized as XML ;) ... will provide an example these days ...

Answer (score -1):

You need to integrate Jersey with Jackson. Look at this tutorial:

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/jersey/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/

Comment: I am not using Eclipse Tomcat and do not have Maven. Do you have any other recommendation? Thanks.